# How to apply jquery slimscroll to body tag

Tags: jquery, slimscroll

How can I apply jquery slimscroll to body Element?

slimscroll can't be 100% height. If it uses "px" instead, it's working good.

What's the issue?

jsfiddle.net/zvsx0k4n

Comment: I edited your post to fix all the typos. Now, if you would like an answer to your question, please be more specific in what you're asking. Read the Stack Overflow help docs if you aren't sure what needs to be included in your question to make it useful.

Comment: thanks dear , i did

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your fiddle.  I see at the bottom you have this:

```
$("#body").slimScroll({
          size: '8px', 
          width: '100%', 
          height: '500px', 
          color: '#ff4800', 
    position: 'right',
          allowPageScroll: true, 
          alwaysVisible: true,     
          railVisible: true

        });
```

If you change the slimscrill height to be 100%, then adjust the height in the $('#body') reference it seems to work just fine.

It looks like your body element itself is set to the height here.  If you inspect the element in the fiddle you can see that the body actually is given the height=200px;